# set method of long variable (setMobile() ) gives error during runtime in action class of struts 2 framework

Tags: struts2

```
package com.kumar.student;

import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class StudentAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String rollNumber;
    private String department;
    private String year;
    private String dob;
    private String email;
    private long mobile;
    private List<String> gender;

    @Override
    public String execute() {

        return "success";

    }

    // all setter & getter method for remaining variable

        public long getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(long mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public List<String> getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(List<String> gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

In the above code setMobile(Long mobile) method gives the below exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.kumar.student.StudentAction.setMobile([Ljava.lang.String;)

Comment: Post a full stacktrace.

Comment: You forgot to ask question.

Comment: What value do you submit?

Comment: I'am submitting a Mobile Number consists of 10-digits like 9052599254